# Installing trim with carpet tack strips already installed?

Tags: flooring, trim, baseboard, carpet

I know that in general, trim should be installed first, followed by tack strips and then carpet. And typically I see something like having the trim be 3/8" to 1/2" off the floor and the tack strip being 3/8" from the trim (this is for home carpet).

However, as I am replacing carpet and trim, I am reusing the existing tack strips that are already installed and was planning on installing the new trim next and then carpet after that. Is this the right order in this case? Or should I just install the trim afterwards now? if I do it first should I still stick to the 1/2" off the ground rule?

Comment: I always installed trim last.

Comment: Same here.  I think it would be quite difficult to get the edges of the carpet onto the tack strips with the trim in the way.

Comment: The advantage of trim before carpet method is it allows caulking and painting to be complete before carpet is installed to prevent damage to carpet. It shouldn't matter to the carpet installers either way.

Comment: Carpet then trim, for the sake of your knuckles. And you’ll be able to get the trim nice and tight.